# How to replace content and output file to a browser?

Tags: php

I output file content to a browser through such code:

```
if($dh = @fopen(@$cachefile, "r"))
{
    fpassthru($dh);
    exit;
}
```

I need to replace some content before output. That is, I need to do something like this:

```
if($dh = @fopen(@$cachefile, "r"))
{
    str_replace("%body%", "black", $dh); // Replace part of content
    fpassthru($dh);
    exit;
}
```

What is the best way to do this?
I use PHP 7.4.7

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. I'm not sure there is a "best" way. This is a simple way.

```
    $content = file_get_contents($cachefile);
    $modifiedContent = str_replace("%body%", "black", $content); // Replace part of content
    echo $modifiedContent;
```